# Complex trig in integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am looking at the solution to an integral of trig functions. I have put the solution below. When I attempted I started with the same method of replacing the cosines with their complex form. However, I used the full form of cosine for the numerator as it is used in the denominator. The question is to prove that it is equal to pi/12. Which, the solutions shown do get (using residues). Wolfram Alpha also affirms this numerically.

Thoughts on why only the first term of cosine's complex form is used?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EU2N9.jpg
Full solution:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTfW1.jpg

*I do not have enough 'points' to add images, apologies.

Comment: Does the solution then take the real part of the computed integral?

Comment: Please type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I updated the question with the full solution. I do not believe the real part is taken.